# Incorrect Output on MSSQL varchar ODBC

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, odbc

I'm using `odbc_exec` to get a `varchar(MAX)` from MSSQL server. however the value is returning like:

`År)2014-0`

It should look like: `59877d4c7baa6-h0d27e80`

Here's some code to help give insight:

```
$conn = odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Native Client};Server=Server;Database=Database;", "Username", "Password");

$out = odbc_exec($conn, "SELECT [uuid] FROM [Database].[dbo].[Table]");

        if (odbc_num_rows($out)) {
            while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($out)) {
                echo $row['uuid']
            }
        }
```

(statement abstracted for example)

Comment: Just to clarify, everything looks good on the sql server side. I can even compare with `=` which was the reason for the data type change.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem this issue is a known bug with no solution to date (PDO ODBC does have a fix)

Changing the SQL Driver to `SQL Server` from `SQL Native Client` resolves this issue, however I am aware of certain performance issues with using this driver.